# Align woocommerce products in one line

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, vertical-alignment

I would like to align woocommerce products in one line, like:

[image]

Here's my actual code:

```
<div class="row">
<ul class="products text-center">
<?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 8
                );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                endwhile;
            } else {
                echo __( 'No products found' );
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

I found this in woocommerce docs, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: This is about settings *(no code is needed)*: Go to **Appearance** > **Customize** first. Then in customizer go in **Woocommerce** > **Product catalog**… Set **"products by row"** value to **`1`** and may be set the desired **"Rows per page"** value too… Then  "Publish". You are done and your products will be aligned vertically as one product by line (by row).

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem